# Selenium: actions.moveToElement.click not working

Tags: java, selenium, action

I can't understand why this isn't working. The Web app that I'm testing has a pop up box that is generated on clicking a button. This popup box contains a table, each row of which is clickable. I have tried numerous implementations of Actions, table row selection etc. but nothing is working. The element is visible to Selenium, it just won't click it. No error is being thrown either.

ADDITIONAL NOTE: I've checked the Action method with other elements and it works so it has to be the selector being used or how it is seeing it. Very strange behaviour. I've also checked it in Firefox with the Selenium IDE and weblement.click() will work on the CSS selector with that.

```
public class ContactDetails {
    WebDriver driverInstance;

public ContactDetails(WebDriver driver){
    this.driverInstance = driver;
}

public void enterContactDetails(){

    //Other code here...

    By validAddress = By.cssSelector("#customerAddress > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td");
        //Validate that the element is visible. Definitely working as intended because I use it elsewhere in the code successfully.
        if (Helper.checkElementVisible(driverInstance, validAddress)){ 
            //if visible:
            WebElement selectAddress = driverInstance.findElement(validAddress);
            //Helper.scrollToElementAndClick(driverInstance, selectAddress);
            Actions actions = new Actions(driverInstance);
            actions.moveToElement(selectAddress).click().perform();
        }
    }
}
```

Helper Class:

```
public class Helper {

    public static void scrollToElementAndClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement webelement){
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(webelement).click().perform();
}
```

The strangest thing is that it worked ok a couple of times when I did this implementation. I then put the Actions code into the now commented out `Helper.scrollToElementAndClick()` method and it stopped working. Then when I went back to this implementation it wasn't working either!

I can't post an image of the popup because it would reveal sensitive info but here is some sample HTML of popup with dummy data:

```
<div class="someDiv" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-1"
style="height: auto; width: 600px; top: 175px; left: 364px; display: block;">
  <div class="anotherDiv">
     <span id="ui-1" class="ui-title"></span> 
     <button class="ui-title-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close"> 
       <span>close</span>
     </button>
  </div>
  <div id="validateCustomerAddress" class="ui-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max height: none; height: 230px;">
<h2 class="aSection" style="color:#666666">Valid Addresses:</h2>
<table id="customerAddress">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ZIP CODE: N/A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 POPLAR WAY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>KINSEY DRIVE</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since, this is a pop up box, try by adding an [Explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to check for the presence of element first and then execute the code with **Action class**.

Comment: @Subh tried that and added a verification println to be sure. According to the explicit wait the element is present and clickable but the click isn't registering

Comment: Okay. Can you please add the relevant HTML code snippet and image of the popup? Furthermore, if its a public site that you're automating, can you please give the URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try combining all the action into one action as shown below and try again.

public class Helper {

```
public static void scrollToElementAndClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement webelement){
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(webelement).click();

action = action.build;
action.perform();
```

}

Also you can try `JavascriptExecuter` as shown below:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", selectAddress);
```

Also consider the possibility of the `td` containing some other element (input, link) which can be clicked(I dont know your html code).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried various different versions of your code above but it's still not working. The element is visible and clickable (verified by Selenium `.isClickable()`) but the click is just not being registered. I even put a println after the click action and it is being printed to the console so there is something else wrong

Comment: I tried a `JavascriptExecutor` and it worked no problem. `JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);` Thanks for your input. Could you explain why this works and not the `Actions` solution?

Comment: I cannot be sure on this without seeing you entire application. I have faced similar issues with Actions in my applications where I was not able to find a valid reason.

Comment: Moslty the javascript click works, because the elemnt is not reachable by the normal way.. maybe the lement is covered

Comment: @adohertyd It all depends on the reachability of the element. I had a switch statement, where I would get an error if you clicked the switch statement, but no error if you clicked the text element inside of the switch element. It depends on where the js click event listener is attached. If the scroll isn't working, I once had the problem, that the layout covered part of the scrolling content and the action scrolled enough so the element would be on screen if it wasn't covered.